# Possible to apply a background color to element that does not get applied to border? (CSS)

Tags: css, background, border

In CSS3, is it possible to apply a background color to an element that does ***not*** get applied to the border?

When you use:

`element { background: red; }`

the background color gets applied to the border area as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes

Using `background-clip` - [**MDN Link**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

> The background-clip CSS property specifies whether an element's background, either the color or image, extends underneath its border.
>
> - border-box
>
> The background extends to the outside edge of the border (but underneath the border in z-ordering).
>
> - padding-box
>
> No background is drawn below the border (background extends to the outside edge of the padding).
>
> - content-box
>
> The background is painted within (clipped to) the content box.

```css
p {
  border: 10px navy;
  border-style: dotted double;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  background: #F8D575;
}
.border-box {
  background-clip: border-box;
}
.padding-box {
  background-clip: padding-box;
}
.content-box {
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

```html
<p class="border-box">The yellow background extends behind the border.</p>
<p class="padding-box">The yellow background extends to the inside edge of the border.</p>
<p class="content-box">The yellow background extends only to the edge of the content box.</p>
```

Comment: Wow!  Thank you so much Paulie!  I think that's exactly what I need.

Answer (score -1):

Simply use:

```
element { background: red; border-color:black; }
```